# Table csvreader: loop over columns

Tags: tables, loops, csvsimple, expandafter

I have a csv file called "data.csv" containing the following data:
1,2,3
4,5,6

I am writing the following table in Latex by using `\csvreader`:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Sue & Karl & Tim \\
\hline
\csvreader[
    no head,
    late after line=\\,
    late after last line=,
    ]{data.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Which correctly yields what I want, i.e.:
[image]

However, instead of manually typing `\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii` inside `\csvreader`, I'd like to achieve that through a for loop. So I've written the following code:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{
        \ifnum\i > 1 
            \& 
        \fi
        \csname csvcol\romannumeral\i\endcsname
    }
}


\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Sue & Karl & Tim \\
\hline
\csvreader[
    no head,
    late after line=\\,
    late after last line=,
    ]{data.csv}{}{\mycommand{3}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, this yields the following:
[image]

Can you please help me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This can be conveniently done with the `readarray` package.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}
1,2,3
4,5,6
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{data.csv}\mydata
\readarray*\mydata\myarray[-,\ncols]
\renewcommand\typesetrowsepchar{\\}
\renewcommand\typesetcolsepchar{&}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Sue & Karl & Tim \\
\hline
\typesetarray\myarray\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about `readarray` package, it seems very convenient!

Answer (score 3):

`csvsimple-l3` provides `\csvlinetotablerow` which does exactly what you want. `csvsimple-l3` can be loaded with either `\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}` or `usepackage{csvsimple-l3}`

```tex
\begin{filecontents*}[noheader,overwrite]{data.csv}
1,2,3
4,5,6
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}

\begin{document}
Original, using \verb|\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii|\par
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  Sue & Karl & Tim \\
  \hline
  \csvreader[
      no head,
      late after line=\\,
      late after last line=,
      ]{data.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\medskip

Using \verb|\csvlinetotablerow|\par
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  Sue & Karl & Tim \\
  \hline
  \csvreader[
      no head,
      late after line=\\,
      late after last line=,
      ]{data.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\medskip

Using \verb|\csvautotabular|\par
\csvautotabular*[
  table head={\hline Sue & Karl & Tim \\ \hline}
]{data.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]