Find Text Between tabs
I copied a sheet from google sheet into a *.txt and want to format it to a pdf.
I could separate it with
\loop\unless\ifeof\mytextfile
\read\mytextfile to\mytextline 

So I have in every loop one of the nextlines.
Now I want to give back the single fields from the gSheet. In the *.txt file they are tab separated, and I can not find a working method to return every string between tabs.
I found \findBetweenTabs{\mystring}, but it is not working. I get always an empty string back.
Can you please help me?
It could not be that difficult?
edit: I write a python code to replace to tabs with the string "aaabbb"
So, can i now go between these chars? \Str\Between seems not to supoort multiple strings like that

Welcome. // Why do you think your problem is related to Tex or Latex, and not to processing of regular expressions?

I am looking for help to use Latex on this way. Why should it not be a problem related to Tex or Latex

you could read the tab separated text file with tex but you will probably find it easier to use an editor or perl or sed etc to convert the tab separated fields to something like \row{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}{ddd}  with each field in an argument then simply defile \row  to do something with the firlds and \input the file.

Why not related to Latex? If you knew, you'd know ... Honestly, as David said there are much more suitable tools for what you are after: a) languages like Perl, php, Python perhaps etc., b) editors like emacs etc., c) OS like Linux. IF you insist on Latex, check these: https://de.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/regexpatch/regexpatch.pdf, https://github.com/latex3/latex3, to mention a few.

So like python with pylatex?
Never tried this, normaly i get everything with Tex but thank you. I woll give it a try

you wouldn't need pylated, just a one-off edit to make the exported file use tex syntax rather than tabs you anyway need to take care of tex-special characters such as { or % that may be in the data and would break your suggested \read loop.

If you just read a file with normal TeX settings you wouldn't get any tabs after tokenisation as TeX converts tabs into spaces, so you'll have to set up the category code of tab to be something else (e.g., 12) and then you can simply separate on those...

Thank you for your upvote.  I tailored my answer to the situation where each file record might have a different number of string fields in it (listofitems excels for this).  If it were certain, in advance, that each file record had the same number of string fields, my approach would vary slightly (readarray is useful for this case), which would allow one more options in formatting the array output, in the fashion of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713736/table-csvreader-loop-over-columns/713759#713759.

Here's an approach using readarray and listofitems packages:
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{junk.txt}
abc defgh   ijk
lm  nop qrstu   vwxyz
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,listofitems}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{\\}
\readdef{junk.txt}\mydata
\setsepchar{\\/ }% <--TAB character (not SPACE)
\readlist\myrecordlist{\mydata}

3rd string of 2nd record is ``\myrecordlist[2,3]''.

Comma-separated strings for each file record are:\\
\foreachitem\z\in\myrecordlist[]{%
  \ifnum\zcnt=1\else\newline\fi
  \foreachitem\zz\in\myrecordlist[\zcnt]{%
    \ifnum\zzcnt=1\else, \fi
    \zz
  }
}
DONE
\end{document}


I tailored the above answer to the situation where each file record might have a different number of string fields in it (listofitems excels for this). If it were certain, in advance, that each file record had the same number of string fields, my approach would vary slightly (readarray is useful for this case, allowing more options in formatting the array output, as shown in the following MWE:
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{junk.txt}
abc defgh   ijk
lm  nop qrstuvwxyz
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{  }% <--TAB character (not SPACE)
\renewcommand\typesetrowsepchar{\\}
\renewcommand\typesetcolsepchar{&}
\begin{document}
\readdef{junk.txt}\mydata
\readarray\mydata\myrecordlist[-,\ncols]

3rd string of 2nd record is ``\myrecordlist[2,3]''.

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\typesetarray\myrecordlist\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

DONE
\end{document}



Note that StackExchange automatically converts tabs to spaces, so you have to be careful with copying and pasting the code (see for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285838/stop-expanding-tabs-into-four-spaces).

@Marijn Thank you for noting that point!

This is just a proof of concept answer. Your question doesn't really tell what you want to achieve so this is just a small example typesetting two tables (one with the full file contents, one with the contents reduced to two columns). More might be possible, you might want to read the documentation of csvsimple.
If you need more than csvsimple offers, you can also use the datatools package, which offers even more functionality.
Anyways, here is the small example parsing a tabulator separated file with csvsimple:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular[separator=tab]{\jobname.txt}

\csvreader
  [separator=tab, head to column names, tabular=ll, table head=Animal & Food\\]
  {\jobname.txt}
  {}
  {\Animal & \Food}
\end{document}



thank you for your Answer.
I figured it our with the following methode:
\newcommand{\extractText}[1]{%
\noindent% Neue Zeile
\def\tempText{#1}% Initialisiere den temporären Text
% Solange der temporäre Text nicht leer ist
\loop
    % Extrahiere den Text zwischen den Zeichenfolgen "aaabbb"
    \StrBehind{\tempText}{aaabbb}[\tempText]% Aktualisiere den temporären Text
    \StrBefore{\tempText}{aaabbb}[\result]% Extrahiere den Teil vor "aaabbb"
   % Überprüfe, ob es sich um das erste Element handelt, und formatiere es entsprechend größer
    \ifnum\the\inputlineno=1\relax%
        \textbf{\result}% Gib den extrahierten Teil in größerer Schrift aus
        heyho
    \else%
        \result% Andernfalls gib den extrahierten Teil normal aus
    \fi
    % Falls der temporäre Text nicht leer ist, füge eine neue Zeile hinzu und fahre fort
    \unless\ifx\tempText\empty%
        \par% Neue Zeile
    \fi
\ifx\tempText\empty\else\repeat% Solange der temporäre Text nicht leer ist

}
So its easy to go over it with a loop for each row
